# How to project specific fields from a document inside an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

here is a typical document

```
{
   title : 'someTitle',
   places : [{name : 'someName', location : 'someLocation'}, {name ...}]
}
```

I have the following query

```
var qs = {title : 'someTitle', places : {$elemMatch : {name : 'someName' } } };
```

where I select a document which matches the title and which contains a document entry within its 'places' array that has name equal to 'someName'. However the issue is that the entries within the places array are large documents, and I only need a couple of fields from that document. I tried projecting the fields like so but it did not work.

```
var projection = {'places.$.name': 1, 'places.$.location' : 1};
```

Which is supposed to return an array with a document containing only the `'name'` and `'location'` property.

I got the following error

```
Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Cannot specify more than one positional proj. per query.
```

*to be clear, I would like to accomplish this without the aggregate framework*

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. You should consider editing your question to show sample document with expected result.

Comment: According, to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitations), you can't do this without the aggregation framework.

Comment: I will switch to the agg framework, I was just abstaining since it is more computationally intensive and this is a core section of my application. Thanks

Comment: I didn't use the `$elemMatch` in my example - maybe that's why I could use a projection on the array. But I had to leave out the `$`. My projection looks like this `var projection = {'places.name': 1, 'places.location' : 1};`. Tested in MongoDB 3.4

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitations)

> Only one positional `$` operator may appear in the projection document.

But you still need to use the [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) operator to get the expected result:

```js
var qs = { title : 'someTitle', 'places.name' : 'someName' };
var projection = {'places.$': 1 };
db.collection.find(qs, projection);
```

Which returns:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("564f52d7d9a433df958b5630"),
        "places" : [
                {
                        "name" : "someName",
                        "location" : "someLocation"
                }
        ]
}
```

Also you don't need the `$elemMatch` operator here use ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) instead.

---

Now if what you want is an array of "name" and "location" for each subdocument in the array then aggregation is the way to go.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 
        'title' : 'someTitle', 
        'places.name' : 'someName' 
    }}, 
    { '$project': { 
        'places': {
            '$map': { 
                'input': '$places', 
                'as': 'place', 
                'in': { 
                    'name': '$$place.name', 
                    'location': '$$place.location'
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Which yields:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564f52d7d9a433df958b5630"),
    "places" : [
            {
                    "name" : "someName",
                    "location" : "someLocation"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "bar",
                    "location" : "foo"
            }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For the fields inside an array, you can project them the same as in embedded object
`var projection = {'places.name': 1, 'places.location' : 1};`

Check this guideline
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-specific-fields-from-embedded-documents